# Problem with integral calculation integral with OOP in Python

Tags: python, oop, scipy, integral, quad

First, i would like to calculate the integral

[image]

and then i' d like to plot a function F(x) but i have the following error:
F() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

x=np.arange(-20,20,0.5)

class NLA():
    def __init__(self,b=-20*10**-15,E=200*10**-9,w0=18*10**-6,t=50*10**-15,s=1.76,A=0.2,L=0.1):
        self.b=b
        self.E=E
        self.w0=w0
        self.t=t
        self.s=s
        self.A=A
        self.L=L
        self.I0=self.s*self.E/(self.t*np.pi*self.w0**2)
        self.a0=(1/self.L)*np.log(10)*self.A
        self.Leff=0.01*(1-np.exp(-self.L*self.a0))/self.a0
        self.c=self.b*self.I0*self.Leff
        
    def f(self,t,x):
        return np.log(1+((self.c*np.exp(-t**2))/(1+self.x**2)))
    
    def F(self,x,t):
        return ((1+x**2)/(self.c*np.pi**(1/2)))*quad(self.f(t),-np.inf,np.inf,args=(x))[0]
    
nla=NLA()
T=nla.F(x)
```

Comment: F(self,x,`t`) asking for this t

Answer (score 0):

```
def F(self,x,t):
    return ((1+x**2)/(self.c*np.pi**(1/2)))*quad(self.f(t),-np.inf,np.inf,args=(x))[0]
```

change to

```
def F(self,x):
    temp = quad(self.f,-np.inf,np.inf,args=(x,))[0]
    return ((1+x**2)/(self.c*np.pi**(1/2)))*temp
```

`quad` is supposed to get a function, in this case `self.f`.  `quad` will call it with the integration variable, `t` and the `args` tuple.

I split of `temp`, so the `quad` calls is easier to see (and if needed to debug).

`F` should not take `t` as an argument.

When using functions like `quad`, follow the documentation carefully.  If anything is confusing, practice with its examples.  I don't think the OOP is causing problems, except that all those "self" may be confusing you, and obscuring the basic `quad` calls.